# Weighted average for specific student, from specific subject

Tags: python, django

I've been learning Python for few days already and I've tried to accomplish a small Django model of school.

My goal for now is to be able to assign a weighted score to a student for a specific subject (for example physics) and then sum these weighted scores and return a weighted average for a student for his subject.

For example, Student A has scores 3 (score) * 2 (weight), 3 * 3 in Physics and 2 * 4, 3 * 1 in Math. My goal is to return:

Student A
Physics average: 2.5

Student A
Math average: 2.2

for now I've been trying to achieve it this way, but it doesn't work. The weighted average won't display at all.

```py
class Score(models.Model):
    scale = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=scales_list)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    weight = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    
    def _weighted_score(self):
        return self.scale * self.weight

    weighted_score = property(_weighted_score)

    def _weighted_average(self):
        qs = self.objects.all().annotate(
            score_sum = sum('scale'),
            weighted_sum = sum('weight'),
            weighted_avg = Sum((F('scale') * F('weight')), output_field=FloatField() ) / Sum('weighted_sum'), output_field=FloatField()
        )
        return weighted_avg
    
    weighted_average = property(_weighted_average)
```

Thanks.

Comment: _but it doesn't work_ Saying "it doesn't work" is not very helpful.  Update the question to show what the code _actually does_, and explain how that differs from what you _want_.

Comment: @JohnGordon you're right. It doesn't display the weighted average at all. Neither through API nor in app.

Comment: There is no code here to _display_ anything; you've only showed us a model.  If the problem is with _display_, then you need to show us that code.

Comment: oh - that makes sense, yea. I haven't created any views yet, I operate for now only on django's admin panel, terminal and restapi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the issue:

```
def _weighted_average(self):
        qs = self.objects.all().annotate(
            score_sum = sum('scale'),
            weighted_sum = sum('weight'),
            weighted_avg = Sum((F('scale') * F('weight')), output_field=FloatField() ) / Sum('weighted_sum'), output_field=FloatField()
        )
        return weighted_avg
```

For one, you can just use `@property` or Django's cached_property for clarity and brevity. Anyways, the issue you're facing is using that `self`. Self refers to the given object you're using. It's a single instance, i.e. like a `.get()` not a `.filter()` so you can't chain any more of those queryset stuff.

Is your intention to make a queryset based on the current filter? If so, you should either make it a `@classmethod` like so:

```
class Blah(models.Model):
    id = BigAutoField()

    @classmethod
    def blah(cls, qs):
        return qs.filter("more filters")

    @property
    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

hi = Blah.objects.get(id=1)
filtered_or_anotated = Blah.blah(qs=hi)
# It's still a single object, but more filtered which of course is redundant.
print(filtered_or_anotated)

# Will show multiple objects since you're adding more filters
print(Blah.blah(Blah.objects.filter(id__in=[1,3,5])))

# Just for property clarity
print(hi.get_id) # 1
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Indeed, my intention is to make a queryset where I take student ID and Subject ID together and then I count all the scores for these 2 IDs and return the average.

Comment: Err if my solution didn't work out for you, then you can grab the current class's type instead: `self.__class__.objects.all()`